# find lowest z value per row

Tags: geometry-nodes

I can find the lowest value of a grid with this node tree (and delete that point) like this:

[image]

[image]

But how can i delete it for each column (so i want to delete the min z value for each (same) x value?

so there should be 10 points missing, one for each x value.

Comment: Oh, I love this question! I have the solution, give me a few minutes that I can summarize this solidly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a solution:

[image]

...at least partially, because with identical points this does not work reliably, of course, because it is not a real sorting and the next point is fetched with the node `Transfer Attribute` *(you know the problem sufficiently, I think)*.

I do it like this:

1. First I separate the lines of the mesh along a certain direction *(you can switch this if you want)* and create a small offset with the node `Random Value`.

   [image]
2. I convert this mesh to curves, because this gives the lines their own index (*Spline Index*).
3. I create a duplicate of this mesh and set the positions using the *Spline Index* for the *X-Axis* and the *Z-Position* for the *Z-Axis*.

   [image]
4. If I now create a `Mesh Line` with the number of splines, and distribute its position also along the *X-axis* with the index, I can finally fetch the position and the index of the nearest point with the node `Transfer Attribute`.

   [image]

As I said, unfortunately not a solution that works perfectly in all cases, but a quite useful solution.

[image]

---

**Update:**

Since **Blender 3.4** a new node is available for this: `Points of Curve`.

This node returns a certain index of a point per spline. The selection of the point is done by an additional passed weighting.

If you use the *Z-positions* as weighting, this node returns the index of the lowest point per spline, which you then only have to filter out:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.4+)*</sub>

Comment: @RayMairlot Please stop removing the formatting. In *Geometry Nodes*, this is the only way to clearly highlight the names of the nodes. Since no code is used here, this doesn't get in the way of code. Thanks!

Comment: It's standard procedure throughout the site to not use formatting for decoration, which means not using it for anything other than what it is intended for.

Comment: @RayMairlot Sorry, but this is not "decoration". *Geometry Node* are a piece of "code" if you like. And sorry if I violate any guidelines here, but it just helps others enormously to distinguish attributes, inputs, outputs and other variables from the nodes available in Blender. It is an essential help for a better understanding. Please make a better suggestion if there is one. But italic, bold is not a solution. Thanks for your understanding!

Comment: @quellenform: of course i will keep my right answer flag on your answer...thanks again for your beautiful solution and your great explanation. Needed some time to understand it ....

Comment: @quellenform: and i can totally understand that you don't want to have your formatting to be removed!!

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to quellenform i now understood the "z stacking" and how he found out the lowest point on z.

I now made my "own" solution without curves but just meshes and this is how it looks:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well done, well interpreted!

Comment: thank you very much!!! i couldn't have figured that out without your help...!